# TFS Build Server not running NUnit TearDown

Tags: tfs, msbuild, nunit, build-process, tfsbuild

I have a global teardown in my unit tests as below:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public partial class TestRunTeardown
{
    [TearDown]
    public static void Teardown()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("getting to tear down");
    }
}
```

The trace outputs in my local window pointing to the same database, but when I run on the TFS build server it never gets hit. The SetupFixture is in the same namespace as the tests. Oddly the SetUp in another file does get hit, just not the teardown.

All tests do run and pass both locally and on the TFS Build Server though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the teardown hit when you run the tests locally in Visual Studio with the Visual Studio test runner?

Comment: @MrHinsh Yes it does

Comment: Where do you expect the "Trace.WriteLine" to output? Because I don't think it will end up in the build output.

Comment: @MrHinsh the Trace gets written in my local output in Visual Studio. I don't expect the Trace to get written anywhere on the server, but I know the teardown code doesn't get hit as the tests run, but teardown doesn't happen.

Comment: Which build template are you using? Should be *template.12.xaml

Comment: @MrHinsh Yep thats the one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, the build controller had an older version of NUnit Core dlls (0.9) so updated them and SpecFlow started to work with the teardown.

Also, the VS NUnit Test ADaptor dlls had to be alongside those core dlls.

Comment: These files should be provided by Nuget and updated automatically, why are they one the "build controller" at all?

Comment: Thats what I thought too, but they are in a separate area under BuildFramework on the BuildController